# SublimeText Codeintel Python library completion

Tags: python, sublimetext2, code-intelligence

Has anyone got any experience adding system Python libraries to Codeintel's index? It's great for completion of project files, but it'll be nice if it can also pick up, for example, PIL methods and Google App Engine libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Globally or on a per-project basis you can define additional directories to scan for code completion. See the [Readme](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel/blob/master/README.rst) here.

Since you're talking about python stuff you would supply `pythonExtraPaths` array values in a settings file:

```
"Python3": {
    "python": '/usr/bin/python3',
    "pythonExtraPaths": []
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. Hence why I'm asking if anyone has any proven methods.

Comment: Hi Ahmed -- this is what mine looks like: {
 "Python": {
        "python": '/usr/bin/python',
        "pythonExtraPaths": ['/usr/lib/python2.7/']
    }
} and it seems to work!